# Best Hosting for Expression Engine?

Tags: ee2, hosting

Whats the best hosting for Expression Engine sites?

Comment: Hi Glen, I'm closing this question as too open-ended and opinion-based (see the [question guidelines](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). You might want to try asking the question on Twitter with the #eecms hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Nexcess.
A hosting solution that’s right for ExpressionEngine, plus they are EllisLab's Official Enterprise Hosting Partner.

https://www.nexcess.net/expressionengine/hosting

Answer (score 0):

Any Linux based server will do but I generally choose Amazon Web Services for enterprise level sites; although I personally run a church based site successfully on a $5 DigitalOcean droplet:

http://digitalocean.com

http://aws.amazon.com/

As of now the only hosting companies that I avoid are the "no-names" and Bluehost.

Note that if you don't have much hosting experience, you're probably better off with a hosting provider that has a "Control Panel" that makes it easy to setup FTP access. MediaTemple utilizes a service called Plesk which is robust and fairly intuitive to use.

http://mediatemple.com

Comment: What are your tips for AWS?

Comment: Usually if you're exploring AWS, you've usually outgrown something smaller (or by experience know the type of services/instances you need). I'd suggest starting with the smaller/slower servers and upgrade as your needs grow.